# spectrogram of a leak in a water pipe

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, spectrogram

I'm doing a work on the acoustic emission of a leak. I am using a 1.80 m cylindrical tube with water, and the leak is simulated by means of a tap that opens after I have applied negative pressure inside the tube.

I am taking this spectrogram as a test on a tube filled with water and simulating a leak. I notice that in the spectrogram there are some horizontal lines visible at some specific frequencies throughout the spectrogram, and I have no idea how to interpret those lines at some specific frequencies.

The sharp difference in the middle of the image is when the tap is turned on.

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram and then, if you still have questions, asking a more specific question.

Comment: Hello! Welcome here. As MBaz says, you really forgot to ask a specific question, and that makes it hard to impossible to really help you as much as we could. Could you really try and edit your question to contain a clear question, and a bit of specific background on the challenges you're facing answering it? Between us engineers: I think this is very interesting problem, but I don't know exactly what the kind of thing you want to learn from your recording, and you sadly don't mention that.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, as I am not fluent in English that may be why I was not able to explain very well. I am taking this spectrogram as a test on a tube filled with water and simulating a leak. I notice that in the spectrogram there are some horizontal lines visible at some specific frequencies throughout the spectrogram, and I have no idea how to interpret those lines at some specific frequencies.

Comment: My perception is that the question is more about the physics rather than the spectrogam (?). As you probably know already, the spectrogram shows the frequency content of a signal versus time. But, in the context of a leaking pipe these lines denote harmonics that the pipes allow to propagate. You can probably relate those harmonics back to the dimensions of the tube and/or the fluid. It sounds like what you are doing is a typical recording of the impulse response. Is it possible to provide some details in the question about what you are working with and what you are after?

Comment: My study is about the acoustic detection of leaks in fuel tanks. My idea is then to record the audio of a leak and characterize the spectrogram obtained. For this I am varying the sizes of the holes and the amount of water inside the tube, observing what conclusions I can draw from the spectrogram obtained. The figure I sent is the spectrogram of the response to a leak of 1mm in diameter with the tube empty.

Comment: the tube is closed and sealed with the microphone suspended inside. Negative pressure is applied and recording starts. After 10 seconds, the leak opens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but my guess on this is: just like air flowing through a flute, water flowing through a tube causes vibrations, tones. The strong tone with several overtones is pretty consistent with this being similar to an air instrument.